# Obtain more information from the user via Inner join Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I supposed in the process developed is such that it must show all the movies that are into film tablen and showing off, but this is how I have tried to do this:

it must find out which genres have in users tablen where after to show the users who like the first.

```
//As I said, I have a session at the top of the code.
int brugerid = Convert.ToInt16(Session["id"]);

    var result = (from f in db.films
    //it must find out which genres have in users tablen where after to show the users who like the first.
    //brugere are users
    //gener It is the genes users like.
        join usersgenerId in brugere.Fk_generId on gener.generId equals usersgenerId.BrugereId
        select new
        {
            image_navn = ((f.imgs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.feature == true)).navn == null ? "default.png" : (f.imgs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.feature == true)).navn),
            image_feature = f.imgs.Where(A => A.feature == true),
            film_navn = f.navn,
            film_id = f.filmId,
            film_tekst = f.tekst,
            film_gener = f.gener.navn
        }).ToList();

RepeaterFilmList.DataSource = result;
RepeaterFilmList.DataBind();
```

**Table information**

Brugere the name
id = BrugereId
Fk_generId belonging to the genes that user has selected.
and many other

Gener is the name
has generId as id

Comment: Is there a question here? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @OmegaMan the problem is that it will not make you inner join in between users and generating tablen.

Comment: If I am correct... your structure is something like... film has genre, user likes certain film genre (therefore user has genre, represented in usergenerId table which has userId (brugerid?) and generId).  You need to fetch all films that matches the user's preferred genre?

Comment: Your solution doesn't include all the object in brugere (only the ones and have the same id as in db.films).  I would use Cat method to combine the two objects, then use GroupBy to combine the objects by Id.

Comment: @JimmyChandra Yes that's right understand, but for example if he likes horror movies so it should come first and everything else will come after,

Comment: Ah so... **show all movies that is in the same genre that the user preferred and then show everything else**, yes?

Comment: @JimmyChandra Yes :)

Comment: Check my edited answer... might not correspond 1 to 1 to your SQL query, but it does solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the question really is: **show all movies that is in the same genre that the user preferred and then show everything else**.

Although the following approach might not be db efficient (too lazy to create the db for this, so I am simulating everything in memory and using Linq to Object to solve the issue), it can certainly be resolved by the following steps:

1. Get the recommendation (matching the user's movie genre preference) like so:

   ```
       var recommendation = 
           from f in films
           from ug in userGenres
           where ug.UserId == user.Id && ug.GenreId == f.GenreId
           select f;
   ```
2. Now that we know what the user preferred, we can further filter this to just the preferred films' Id... and use that to get the rest of the unpreferred films (basically anything not matching the preferred film Ids):

   ```
       var recommendedFilmIds = recommendation.Select(f => f.Id);
       var everythingElse =
           from f in films
           where !recommendedFilmIds.Contains(f.Id)
           select f;
   ```
3. Finally, join them together using `Union` and injecting the nessary fields for display purpose like `Genre.Name`, etc. like so:

   ```
       var filmList = recommendation.Union(everythingElse).Select(f => new { 
           f.Id, 
           f.Title, 
           Genre = genres.Where(g => g.Id == f.GenreId).Select(g => g.Name).First() 
   });
   ```

And there you have it, the combined list will now contains both preferred films first (at top), followed by unpreferred films afterward.

The simulated tables are as follows: `films` which contains its own `Id` and  `genreId` and `userGenres` which contains many to many relationship between `user` and `genre` and a particular `user` object which contains the `user id`.

An example of this can be found at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Skuq3o

If you use EF, and you have a navigation property to `genre` table and you want to include those table as part of the query, use `.Include(x => x.genre)` or whatever you call your genre table after `from f in films` to avoid n+1 select if you wish to include the genre info in the final select clause.